# javascript window['func'] with parameters returning undefined instead of function

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, modal-dialog, function-calls

I'm trying to pass json to a function, which in turn takes the json and displays dynamic ui-modal dialog. When I try to pass the button events(functions) , thy are getting executed and returning undefined how can I pass reference to the function instead of actual function. Sorry for my english the code below explains much better:

```
//heres my ui model function
function showDialog(json) {
        var dialog_id = json.id;
        if(typeof($(dialog_id)[0]) === "undefined") {
            $(body).append("<div id='dialog-confirm'></div>");
        }
        $(dialog_id).html(json.confirmationText);
        $(dialog_id).dialog({
            modal: true,
            title: json.title,
            height: 250,
            width: 400,
            buttons:json.buttons
        });
```

}

```
//here is the function which calls
showDialog({"id":"#dialog-confirm","title":"blaa","confirmationText":'randomtext',"buttons":[{"text":"Cancel","click":window["noAction"]},{"text":"Confirm","click":window["doAction"]('pram1','param2')}]});

var noAction = function(){$('#dialog-confirm').dialog('close');}
var doAction = function(param1,param2){//do some logic};
```

`noAction` function is working correctly. (when the model is called and cancel is clicked the dialog disappears)

`doAction` function is getting evaluated when the function showDialog is called and is returning `undefined` (verified in console). How can I bind doAction to confirm button. (ie, when Confirm is clicked I want to call doAction).

P.S: I know how to do it with custom on click handlers but I think it would be a work around but not the actual solution.

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try 
`showDialog({..., "buttons":[...,{"text":"Confirm","click":function(){doAction(param1,param2);} }]})`

Comment: yep tried it...same behavior the function is getting evaluated as soon as the showDialog is called.. I want it to execute only when Confirm is clicked. Thanks

Comment: thanks though your answer didn't solve my problem it helped me in what I was doing wrong :) upvote